# Reset Focus in Windows 8 Apps

Tags: c#, windows-8, visual-studio-2012

So I have a button that initiates a popup. In the popup I have it to detect when the enter key is pressed when the textbox is in focus and to submit the data and close the popup. However, when I close the popup the button that was pressed to initiate the popup regains focus and receives the key down event and thus opens the prompt again.

So I ask: Is there a way to reset focus from all elements?

Comment: You are asking for a band-aid for a pretty dreadful bug in your code.  Fix the bug.

Comment: I don't even know what's causing the "bug". All I have is a Click event that shows a popup object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this for right after the popup closes.

```
FirstButton.Focus(Windows.UI.Xaml.FocusState.Unfocused);
```

Not sure how your code is set up but maybe do something like:
(assuming pop up is within the same window as the original button)

```
       //in the button two clicked function

        if (YourPopUp.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
        {
            //do data sending
            //collapse pop up
            FirstButton.Focus(Windows.UI.Xaml.FocusState.Unfocused);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, it feels a bit hackish but I guess that will have to do. I wish I knew why stuff like this happens, but a lot of weird stuff has happened in my ventures into Windows 8 apps so I've accepted it. Thanks, again!

Comment: No problem glad it worked. but yes its hackish. Maybe use on key up instead of on key down for when the enter button is pressed thus eliminating the possibility of it doing two things.